# How to use a gem method (returning strings) as custom validation in rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm new to RoR/Gems, this is a basic question.

I created a gem, MyNameGem, in order to learn the process. It contains these methods:

```
def returnValidationString1
  puts 'Validation String'
end
def returnValidationString2
  puts 'ANother Validation String'
end
```

I included the gem in a simple rails app, everything seems to be working as expected.
I this to my model:

```
validates :name => MyNameGem.returnValidationString1
```

What I'm trying to create is a gem that I can use inside a validation routine. So, for example, I want to do this: validates :name => (call my gem method, return a string, and use that string as the validation requirement)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function of `puts` is to put things to the console, so that's exactly what it will do. What your validates call is doing is kind of unusual though, and doesn't seem to make any sense. Your code evaluates to:

```
validates :name => (puts "MyNameGem")
```

That really doesn't mean anything. `puts` usually returns `nil`.

If you want to write a custom validation routine that's stored in a gem, that's a different question.

Comment: I see what you're saying. What I'm trying to create is a gem that I can use inside a validation routine. So, for example, I want to do this: validates :name => (call my gem method, return a string, and use that string as the validation requirement)

Comment: I can sort of make out what you're saying, but that simply won't work. That's not how `validates` expects to take arguments. You can return a Hash if you want, that would work better: `validates :name, MyGem.my_method` for instance.

Answer (score 1):

`puts` only prints to console.

if you want to return 'MyNameGem' write `return 'MyNameGem'` or simply `'MyNameGem` because the last line gets returned automatically.